# ASP.NET custom validator is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I've done everything [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx) told me to do, but it's not working, i've seen people posting about this problem and being told to add a required field validator, i've done that, still not working.

Here's the client side part

```
                <asp:CustomValidator 
                    ID="CustomValidator1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" 
                    ErrorMessage="Username already exists" 
                    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" 
                    ValidateEmptyText="True" <!--tried without this line-->
                    ValidationGroup="form">  <!--tried without this line-->
                </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Here's the C# server side code

```
        protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args){
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
```

looks pretty simple, right ? it should keep appearing all the time, right ?
well, it only appears at the beginning and then disappears forever and that's because I have this line in the page_load() method, but i also have it in the button_click() method.

```
Page.Validate();
```

Comment: what does your submit button look like?

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="71px" />`

Comment: `        `protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Page.Validate();
//other code line, not imp
         }`

Comment: you definitely need the `ValidationGroup` removing as the button doesn't have one.

Comment: Also `Page.Validate` won't validate a group unless its called as `Page.Validate("form");`. Are you checking for `Page.IsValid` after the `Validate()` call?

Comment: in the button_click even handler this the main code
`Page.Validate();
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {//my code goes here}
}`

So, yeah, when i click it it shows up after loading the page again, BUT after all the other required fields validators disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, remove the validation group, and add in `Text`:

```
<asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="CustomValidator1" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" 
    ErrorMessage="Username already exists" 
    Text="Username already exists"
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" 
    ValidateEmptyText="True">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

`ErrorMessage` will show in a `ValidationSummary` control and `Text` should show where the validator is.

Update the button to cause validation (I believe true is the default anyway, but lets be explicit):

Then check if the page is valid after click, `Page.Validate` doesn't need to be called as it will be automatically for things that `CauseValidation`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (Page.IsValid)
   {
       // Do Cool Stuff
   }
}
```

Additionally, drop a breakpoint on the click method when checking it as you don't have any client side wiring (e.g. `ClientValidationFunction="somejsfunction"` on the validator) so you will only hit this code when you get through to server side validation.

Comment: same problem: 

in the button_click event handler the main code I have `Page.Validate(); if (Page.IsValid) {//my code goes here} }` So, yeah, when i click it it shows up after loading the page again, BUT after all the other required fields validators disappeared, you get what i'm saying ?

Comment: see edit, you could be being blocked getting to _server side validation_ by other _client side validation_ on the rest of the form.

Comment: if you update your post with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'll spin it up in a test app in my ide in the morning (midnight here) and take a more detailed look in the morning.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaah yes, that makes so much sense, i guess i'm gonna have to use Javascript for that one :)

Comment: I wanna upvote your answer, but i can't because i only have 12 rep, if you upvote my Q, then i'll have enough to upvote you <3